# Android, Custom ListAdapter get TextView-Text

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I coded an own Adapter and added it to my ListActivity via an ListView. 
The reason why I wrote an own Adapter is, that i had to make some layout changes to the list-entrys. In every entry of the list i've got 3 TextViews.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myNr"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:text="id" 
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Editor: " />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="Date: " />
</LinearLayout>
```

The next thing i did, was to implement a "onListItemClick-Methode". Afterwards i implemented a onListItemLongClick - Listener with the following code:

in onCreate of the Activity i added:

```
 registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

then i added the following methode:

```
Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
         AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
         info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            long id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
        }
```

where "id" is the index of the item in the list. 
I now want to get the Text of the texview with the id="myNr of this ListItem.
Is there any way get this Text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found another way to set an ItemLongClickListener. Therefore I also found a way to get the Text I am displaying.

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int row, long arg3) {
   String[] tmp = (String[]) arg0.getItemAtPosition(row);
   //tmp[0] ist the Text of the first TextView displayed by the  clicked ListItem 
   return true;
   }});
```

Answer (score 18):

`view` is the list item, so you can do

```
String s =(String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myNr)).getText();
```

Answer (score 9):

just take reference of of the text view if you extending a **BaseAdapter** like

```
Listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

TextView tx =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            String s = tx.getText().toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "string : "+s);
```

Answer (score 4):

I found none of the above solutions to work. As an *alternative* you can:

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
{

   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long id) 
   {

    Cursor c = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String tableValue = c.getString(1);

        return true;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I found was :

```
@Override  
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);  
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =     (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;

        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
        View children = vg.getChildAt(info.position);
        TextView child = (TextView) children.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        String s= child.getText().toString();
            menu.setHeaderTitle(s);  
            menu.add(0, view.getId(), 0, "Serve");  
            menu.add(0, view.getId(), 0, "View");  

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the TextView at the position of the item the person long-pressed, you can get it out using something like this:

```
String s = ((TextView) view.getItemAtPosition(info.position)).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i also thought so. But when i implement this i just get the Text of the first TextView in the List. That means I am able to get the text of the desired TextView but it is always the text of the first list-entry. Isn't there an option to adress the longClickedList-entry?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help but I am afraid it still doesnt work. 
if i add the line you suggested, it underlines "getItemAtPosition" and says: 
--The method getItemAtPosition(int) is undefined for the type View--

He suggests to cast the view to a AdapterView, so it looks the following:

```
String s = ((TextView) ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) view).getItemAtPosition(info.position)).getText();
```

When i run this and make a long click on the item, i recieve an "ClassCastException"

Answer (score 0):

In this method you will get the item related to your list item.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem aItem) {
  AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) aItem.getMenuInfo();
  Object entity =  (Object) todoList.getAdapter().getItem(menuInfo.position);
  switch (aItem.getItemId()) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            String title = (String) ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText();
                String  artist=(String)((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText();

                     //System.out.println(s);
                        Toast.makeText(CustomizedListView.this,"Title = "+title+"\n"+"Artist = "+artist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                            

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an ArrayList of ArrayLists as my data source for the CustomAdapter, so I use

```
menu.setHeaderTitle(Messages.get(info.position).getUserName());
```

Answer (score 0):

using `HashMap`

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            HashMap m = (HashMap) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
            System.out.println("itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = " + id + " o = " + m.get("YOUR_KEY"));
        }
    });
```