# how to get listitem text in onItemClick listener?

Tags: android

I have created a list view and i have added some item, can anybody help me to get the item text in on Item Click listener?

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            Object o = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String keyword = o.toString();
            Log.v("value ", "result is " + keyword);

        }
    });
```

I have tried the above code but it does not work...

Comment: Hope this link will help you

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724937/android-custom-listadapter-get-textview-text

Answer (score 8):

I assume you have `TextView` on the item.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(position - lv.firstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.mylistviewtextview);
            String keyword = txt.getText().toString();
            Log.v("value ", "result is " + keyword);

        }
    });
```

or you can retrieve the text from the `ArrayList` you feed the `ListView`

Comment: in my case it's bit difficult because it have loaded the arraylist from another class....

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the correct event to intercept for selection is `onItemSelected` because a selection might not have been made in the onClick handler. And then the question has been well treated [here on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433952/android-list-view-selected-item-1)

Comment: Thanks!  between this and the answer above, they both helped me out after googling this exact thing.